# Subword Info in FastText Wiki-Trained Vectors

Tags: fasttext

Does anyone know if the word vectors that facebook opensources (specifically the ones here https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/pretrained-vectors.html) contain subword vectors, or if they just include the resulting full word vectors. My hope was that they would contain subwords, but I'm having trouble finding them and can't seem to find an explicit answer to this question anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

`fastText` gives you two possible solutions:

1. use the .vec file containing only word embedding vector
2. use .bin file containing also subword vectors and model parameters.

Actually using .bin file you can get the embedding for every word you want, while with the .vec file you have a fixed number of available vector (still a large number).